# How to add to array without ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

Can anyone answer this question?

```
public class AddingArray {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      int arry1[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
      int arry2[] = {4,3,7,9,3,5};

      for(int i = 0; i <arry1.length; i++){
          int result = arry1[i] + arry2[i];
          System.out.println("Result "+result);
      }
   }
}
```

Whenever I try executing the above code I get the error Exception in

```
thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6   at
basics.AddingArray.main(AddingArray.java:9)
```

But,my output should be like this 6,6,11,14,9,12,9

Comment: both arrays are of different sizes.

Comment: @RajuS, what's the expected output in this case?

Comment: suppose you have two arrays `{2,1}` and `{1,2,3}` what is your expected output

Comment: If you're just adding you can just add over the first `array` then add over the second `array`. Addition does not care in what order you add it.

No need to over-complicate by adding elements from different arrays together.

Comment: @aioobe has a very relevant point.  The question "what's the right way to do X?" is hard to answer if nobody knows what X actually _is_.   Your example computes pairwise sums of the elements in two parallel arrays, and it throws an exception if the arrays are different lengths.  In many applications, throwing the exception _is_ the right answer in that case.

Comment: Dear Folks, my output should be lilke this 6,6,11,14,13,12,9

Answer (score 0):

It is because your loop will go from 0 to 6 (which is the `array1.length - 1`) and your `array2` only has 6 elements (so from `0` to `5`).

So when you are accessing `arry2[6];` It will give you the [`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html).

You could change your for loop to go to the length of the smallest array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arry2.length; i++){ /*Do what you want */ }
```

Or add an element in `array2`, but that is yours to decide since I do not know your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As people have mentioned, one of yours arrays is literally shorter than the other. Take two blocks and overlay them over only one block. The second (in this case index 1 block) would fall into the abyss, because the block that was supposed to catch it never existed.

I would make sure both of them are of the same size. If you do want to leave em as they are, I would do this:

```
int result = 0;

try
{
   for(int i = 0, length = array2.length; i < length; i++)
   {

      result = array1[i] + array2[i];
      System.out.println("Result is: " + result);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("You tried to do something that resulted in an error");
       System.out.println("Your previous result was: " + result);
    }
 }
```

SO, assuming that I still recall how to do basic arrays, what this code will do is that it will catch any errors thrown by your code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make this as simple and understandable as possible, with no fancy annotations:

1. You have two int arrays, of not equal lengths, and you wish to add the index-paired numbers to an array of the sums. However, if one of the arrays does not have any more numbers, the value of the longest array will be the result.

   ```
   public class AddingArray {
       public static void main(String[] args){
           int arry1[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
           int arry2[]={4,3,7,9,3,5};
   ```

You need to determine the length of the longest array. You can do this with a `Math.max()`-method, where you give the length of each array as parameters:

```
      int biggestArrayLength = Math.max(arry1.length, arry2.length);
```

Then, instead of `for(int i=0;i<arry1.length;i++){`, you write:

```
      for(int i=0;i<biggestArrayLength;i++){
```

Now it doesn't matter which of the two arrays is the biggest one.

Inside the loop, I would define two ints, representing a value from each of the two arrays:

```
      int value1 = arry1[i];
      int value2 = arry2[i];
```

however, this will give an error when the smallest array does not have any more elements. We need to check if the array actually has an element with index i. index numbers in arrays start with 0. so if the length is 7, the 7 elements will have index numbers from 0-6. In other words, only index numbers that are lower (and not equal) to length, is valid numbers:

```
      int value1 = 0;
      int value2 = 0;

      if(arry1.length > i){
          value1 = arry1[i];
      }
      if(arry2.length > i){
          value2 = arry2[i];
      }

      int result = value1 + value2;
      System.out.println("Result "+result);
  }
```

}
}

Now, if you need to put these in a third array, say named sumArray, this would be the complete code:

```
public class AddingArray {
  public static void main(String[] args){
      int arry1[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
      int arry2[]={4,3,7,9,3,5};

      int biggestArrayLength = Math.max(arry1.length, arry2.length);

      int[] sumArray = new int[biggestArrayLength];
      for(int i=0;i<biggestArrayLength;i++){

          int value1 = 0;
          int value2 = 0;
          if(arry1.length > i){
              value1 = arry1[i];
          }
          if(arry2.length > i){
              value2 = arry2[i];
          }

          int result = value1 + value2;
          sumArray[i] = result;
          System.out.println("Result "+result);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `arry1` is longer than `arry2` when you make the last iteration through the loop `arry2[i]` returns null because there is no element to return. 
either do:

 `if(arry2[i] != null) {
    //run your adding code
 }`
or change your arrays to be the same size

Comment: No, arry2[I] is not null - it does not exist. That is why the OP is getting the ArrayOutOfBounds exception. Your test for null will throw the same exception.

Comment: Oh you're right, he would need to check if i < arry2.length

Answer (score -1):

Edit: The reason it is not working properly is because you are using the length of the largest array as the conditional within the for loop. This condition allows you to attempt to access the 2nd array at a location that does not exist, which is why you are getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Can we stop the downvoting?

End edit----

If you want to add up all of the elements in the array use this code.

```
    public class AddingArray {
      public static void main(String[] args){
          int arry1[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
          int arry2[]={4,3,7,9,3,5};
          int result = 0;

          for(int i=0;i<arry1.length;i++){
              result+=arry1[i];
          }
          for(int j=0; j < array2.length; j++){
              result += array2[j];
          }

          System.out.println("Result: "+ result);
      }
}
```

if you are trying to sum individual elements as you loop you can do the following. This will properly handle 2 arrays of different length regardless of which one is longer.

```
    public class AddingArray {
      public static void main(String[] args){
          int arry1[]={2,3,4,5,6,7,9};
          int arry2[]={4,3,7,9,3,5};
          int result = 0;
          for(int i=0;i<arry1.length;i++){
              result=arry1[i];
              if(i < array2.length){
                 result += array2[i];
              }
              System.out.println("Result: "+ result);
          }
          for(int j = i; j < array2.length; j++){
              System.out.println("Result: "+ array2[j]);
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: This isn't at all what his code is supposed to do. If you look at how the loop is set up, he prints the addition of each pair of array values. Eg: He prints arry1[0] + arry2[0], then prints arry1[1] + arry2[1] etc

Comment: His code conflicts with his question. Should we assume his code is correct if he is asking for help fixing it or his question is correct?

Comment: "Adding two arrays" doesn't necessarily mean he wants the sum of all the elements. For instance, adding two arrays to me would be concatenating them into one array. I think it's better to assume his code does what he wants minus the error rather than make an assumption like this. Even better would have been to post a comment asking him :)

Comment: Fine. I added the section showing how to add the individual elements of two arrays of potentially different lengths.